# Visual studio debugging dll not stopping

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, emgucv

I am using visual Studio 2015. 
I have an Windows Forms Application in Visual C# with lots of code using [EmguCv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). 3.0.0.  I am having trouble debugging me code do to the following problem:

When I run this code(With an error)

```
        string theFileName = @"C:\temp\lena.jpeg";
        Rectangle theROI = new Rectangle(-1, 0, 42, 42); //<-Error.
        Mat theImage = new Mat(theFileName, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LoadImageType.Unchanged);
        Mat theExc = new Mat(theImage, theROI);//<-Here the program just stops with no error.
```

The program just stops. I do not get any indication where there is an error.

Sometimes i get an Emgu.Cv.Util has throw on excpetion. But no hints what line of code gave the problem. I don´t want to debug Emgu I want to find errors in my own code.

I have used both setting on "Enable Just My Code"

The Output window just writes:
The program '[25312] VisionBox.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am using

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL

Microsoft .NET Framework

Version 4.6.01038

I have used Both:
Debug...Any CPU and
Debug..x64 
With the same result.
Also tried:

```
            try
        {
            string theFileName = @"C:\temp\lena.jpeg";
            Rectangle theROI = new Rectangle(-1, 0, 42, 42); //<-Error.
            Mat theImage = new Mat(theFileName, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LoadImageType.Unchanged);
            Mat theExc = new Mat(theImage, theROI);//<-Here the program just stops with no error.
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

            var theMessage = ee.Message;
        }
```

Does not work. I never get the Exception.

I also tried:
1. Create a new Windows Form Application. File->New->Project. Selecting "Windows Form Application" Ok.

2. Add Reference Emgu.CV.dll and Emgu.Util.dll.
3. Copying the x64 and x86 folder from the Emgu folder to the folder of the exe file from the project.
4. Add button to form and copying the code from above to the button1_Click function
5. Adding using Emgu.CV to Form1.cs
6. F5. ->  press button

Result: The program stops and the output windows writes:"Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.dll
The program '[21552] WindowsFormsApplication2.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
"

What is working is if I follow the steps above but using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: What is VisionBox.exe?  Is that the name of your app's executable?  Just grabbing at straws here but are you building in Debug mode or release mode?  Make sure your build condiguration is set to debug not release.  Release doesn't have any debug symbols.

Comment: yes. This is just the name

Comment: The Configuration Manager is set To: Debug x64 Build

Comment: -? Your Platform target should be whatever your dependencies are.  So if emgucv is 32 bit only, then set your platform to x86.  And you should build it as debug, not release.

Comment: It looks like Emgu CV has two versions, one for x86, and one for x64.  So if set your platform target to x86 or x64 depending on which one you are using.  Not doing so might be what causes it to bomb out like that because if you are set to any cpu and it's x86 and you are on a 64 bit Windows, it will fail to load the dll because a 64 bit process cannot load a 32 bit assembly and vice versa.

Comment: Now set to Debug-Any CPU and same problem (O:

Comment: Added an answer for what I think might be your issue.

Comment: did you set any prebuild or postbuild command.